# How to select pairwise element from two array and give them to two different function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array of getters `G = ["g1", "g2", "g3"]`and another array of setters `S = ["s1", "s2"]`. Further I have following two functions

```js
callGetters(index???) {
   targetParameter = G[index???]; 
}

callSetter (index???) {
  targetParameter = S[index???]
}
```

Now, I am trying to call above two functions with this pairwise sequence of selected/picked parameters i.e.

```js
choose g1, s1 then callGetters()/callSetter () 
.. g1, s2, then callGetters/callSetter () 
...g2, s1, then callGetters()/callSetter ()
 ...g2,s2, then callGetters()/callSetter ()
.. g3, s1,  then callGetters()/callSetter () 
..g3, s2,   then callGetters()/callSetter () ..
```

I could not imagine how to code the above scenario in `javascript/nodejs`.  I am newbie in `JavaScript/Nodejs`, so accept my apology, if this is not asking in a standard way or not used proper terminologies...

Comment: What do you want to call the setters with, and what do you want to do with the return value of the getters?

Comment: definitely setter to change values ... actually, I have to just pick pair wise values from S/G array and just call some function, accordingly , nothing else...

Comment: Setters *require* exactly one parameter. If you call a setter without a value, it may likely throw an error or have unexpected results. Is that really OK?

Comment: yes, that's why, i said pair wise... no null values.. it must be two valus... one from s and other from g...  (si,gi) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(let i = 0; i < G.length; i++){
  for(let j =0; j < S.length; j++){
    console.log(G[i],S[j])
    //do whatever 
  }
}
```

you can try two for loops like above.

Comment: where is 'i' ... ?

Comment: in first for loop

Comment: i see now the updated thanks..